# Add a button inside the "Product Name" attribute of a product in my Magento AdminPanel

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, admin-panel

I would like to add a button to the **'Product Name'** attribute within the **product information tab**, but I'm unsure of how to achieve this. Below is my **product_form.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">product_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="childrenFromMeta" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <reloadItem>product-details.attribute_set_id:value</reloadItem>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Save"/>
            <button name="addAttribute" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\AddAttribute"/>
            <button name="back" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Back"/>
            <button name="ai" class="Improove\Task\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CustomButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <deps>
            <dep>product_form.product_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="product_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider" name="product_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <htmlContent name="gallery" sortOrder="22">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="wrapper" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Images</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <wrapper>
                <canShow>true</canShow>
                <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
            </wrapper>
        </settings>
        <block name="gallery" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content" as="content">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="parentComponent" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.block_gallery.block_gallery</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\ProductVideo\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\NewVideo" name="new-video" template="Magento_ProductVideo::product/edit/slideout/form.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </htmlContent>
</form>
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Can you add more information about what this button is supposed to do ?

Comment: its something like the image that suncartstore insert in the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below steps to add custom button under Product Name Container.

Your Above requirement can achieve by implement **Product Form Modifier** approach.

Step 1: Create etc/adminhtml/di.xml file

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="advancedUrlButton" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">
                    StackOver\ProductBtn\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\NameBtn
                </item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Step 2: Create modifier class file \Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\NameBtn.php

```
<?php

namespace StackOver\ProductBtn\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class NameBtn extends AbstractModifier
{
protected ArrayManager $arrayManager;
protected Http $request;

public function __construct(ArrayManager $arrayManager, Http $request)
{
    $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    $this->request = $request;
}

/**
 * @param array $meta
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function modifyMeta(array $meta): array
{
    $containerPrefix = "container_";
    $fieldCode = 'name';
    $containerPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath($containerPrefix . $fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');

    $value['children']['create_productname_button'] = [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'title' => __('Extra Button'),
                    'formElement' => 'container',
                    'buttonClasses' => 'namegenerator-button-class',
                    'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-small',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'StackOver_ProductBtn/form/element/namegenerate',
                    'componentType' => 'container',
                    'disabled' => false,
                    'component' => 'StackOver_ProductBtn/js/advancename',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/components/button/container',
                    'additionalForGroup' => true,
                    'provider' => false,
                    'source' => 'product_details',
                    'displayArea' => 'insideGroup',
                    'sortOrder' => 55,
                    'dataScope' => $fieldCode,
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ];
    $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge($containerPath, $meta, $value);
    return $meta;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function modifyData(array $data)
{
    return $data;
}
}
```

Step 3: Then create Template file for Custom Btn
StackOver/ProductBtn/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/element/namegenerate.html

```
<button type="button"
    css="buttonClasses"
    attr="'data-index': index, 'aria-labelledby': ariLabelledby">
<span attr="'id': buttonTextId" text="title">Click</span>
</button>

<if args="childError">
<strong class="_error">
    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-messages">
        <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message _error">
            <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-icon"></span>
            <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-tooltip"
                  data-bind="i18n: 'This element contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.'">This element contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</strong>
</if>
```

Step 4: Create Custom Btn Component File to write your custom btn click events.

StackOver/ProductBtn/view/adminhtml/web/js/advancename.js

```
define(['Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button', 'jquery'],
function (Button, $) {
    'use strict';

    console.log("Component has been loaded");

    return Button.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
        }
    })
})
```

[image]

*Please let us know, if have any doubt's regarding the same.*
***And Don't forget to up-vote the answer.***

Comment: when i click the button, i can't do nothing and i have changes in the js file.

Comment: @VicenteRomão you need to add/bind click event on your html button template like this
<button type="button"data-bind="click: nameGenerate"> and in component js file you can define function to handle the event like this nameGenerate: function () {console.log("button click")}